# Rails 3 has_many, how to create object and its relationships from index action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, has-many

I have Bands and Codes and Users.

the key/codes will let a user do things with the band.  I am on the Band#show action and need to generate a code, and then have that code be related to the user and the band.

so:

Code belongs_to :band, belongs_to :user
Band has_many :codes
User has_many :codes

So now I need to use a form_for (I think) to create a button which when pressed does the following:

check if a user has a code with that band(user can have one code per band)

If not:

- Creates a 6 digit alphanumeric key/code (I know ActiveSupport can do
  it: <%= SecureRandom.hex(3)%> but this needs to be in the model or
  controller)
- Set the correct associations, this code works for this user and this band.  I am using Devise so I have access to a current_user method
- and return the user to the Band#show
  action

If the user already has a code for that band, then they are given an error "You already have a code"

I want to eventually make this call with Ajax to keep from reloading the page but for now I am just trying to build the function.

Comment: Check the RoR documentation for associations http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: I have done that.  And while it helps, and I was able to build my models based on it, I am struggling with next steps.  Even some direction would be cool, what types of things should I look for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, I would create the following route in your routes.rb:

```
resources :bands do
  post :add_code, :on => :member
end
```

This will create an additional route looking like this:

```
add_code_band_path POST   /bands/:id/add_code(.:format)  {:action=>"add_code", :controller=>"bands"}
```

Then from your views you can use the button_to helper method to send a post request like this:

```
<%= button_to "Add Code", add_code_band_path(@band), :method => :post %>
```

When the user clicks on that button then you can handle the rest from the controller action like this:

```
class BandsController < ApplicationController
  ...

  def add_code
    @band = Band.find(params[:id])
    @code = current_user.codes.find_or_create_by_band_id(@band.id)
    render :action => :show
  end
```

Lastly, the actual randomized code I would generate from a before_create callback from the Code model itself, like this:

```
class Code < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...

  before_create :generate_code

private
  def generate_code
    self.code = SecureRandom.hex(3)
  end
end
```

Then if you think it's necessary then you could also add other verifications like only showing the Add Code button if there is no Code existing or perhaps add error messages if a user tries to add another code for the same band, but I leave that to you. The button_to helper also supports Ajax by using `:remote => true` so you can further develop it the way you want.

Comment: Danne, this is a huge help.  I was struggling to see how to get this done and this does it.  The only issue I can see is that it doesn't seem to be creating the code.  Do I need to add @code = Code.new in the show action in the controller?

Comment: I am sorry I did more digging about find_or_create_by and I think maybe I am not passing enough to it. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html talks about passing more methods to it...

Comment: I was able to resolve my issue with this slight modification: find_or_create_by_band_id(@band.id, :user_id => current_user.id)

Comment: Hmm, that was strange. The user_id attribute should have been set automatically as long as you created the code from the current_user.codes association. Oh well, glad you got it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try in your band/user codes, has_many :through

You'll have to create a join table and join model, but I think it's what you're looking for.